# Should I use the ternary operator or the || operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have found two ways of coding a conditional assignment, but both give the same result:

```
function onClickEvent(e){ 
    e = win.event || e,  //These are
    var ev=e.target || e.srcElement;  // good?
    alert(ev.innerHTML);
}
```

or

```
function onClickEvent(e){
    e = (win.event) ? win.event : e;  //or
    var ev = (e.target) ? e.target : e.srcElement; // these are?
    alert(ev.innerHTML);
}
```

Is one approach preferred over the other? If yes, why?

Comment: They both work, and there's not even a functional difference. Use whichever you like.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Do whatever you prefer, or which suits you most. If you work as part of a team, negotiate the standards you should *all* follow, and then follow those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the shortest, most communicative code possible.

IMO the first is canonical JS for optional argument assignment and would be preferred.

The second, while equivalent, requires more effort to comprehend, *unless* you're conversant in JavaScript. If you opt for the latter, *please* use more whitespace and drop the parens.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, the second one, because it is more readable and common-sensical.

Comment: It's not a matter of "common sense"; the first is idiomatic JS. That doesn't automatically confer readability, but it's not "common sense" to ignore idiomatic language constructs. (IMO)

Comment: Common Sense means, commonly available sense, meaning, it is in the format which is more likely to be recognizable by more people. Upvoted you, btw ;-)

Comment: I agree to use the second one, it's more readable and is used in other languages (like C#).  That's my opinion.

Comment: @contactmatt So developers should code to the "lowest common denominator" and only use features found in language Xyz? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @DaveNewton You have a point, it's just more readable to _me_ so that's what I prefer, especially since most of my web development is in C#/JavaScript.   I also do not like programming to the lowest common denominator, unless I do so implicitly since I am the lowest common denominator :P

Comment: @DaveNewton Simplicity is profit. Complexity does not hurt when the code is perfect. But it is impossible to write perfect code in a large project. So simplicity wins.

Comment: @srini.venigalla And idiomatic JS is the simpler.